# Select distinct very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a table where I store rows with external ids. Quite often I need to select latest timestamp for given external ids. Now it is a bottleneck for my app

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("T1"."external_id") "T1"."external_id", "T1"."timestamp" 
FROM "T1" 
WHERE "T1"."external_id" IN ('825889935', '825904511')
ORDER BY "T1"."external_id" ASC, "T1"."timestamp" DESC
```

Explain:

```
Unique  (cost=169123.13..169123.19 rows=12 width=18) (actual time=1327.443..1334.118 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=169123.13..169123.16 rows=12 width=18) (actual time=1327.441..1334.112 rows=2 loops=1)
         Sort Key: external_id, timestamp DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..169122.91 rows=12 width=18) (actual time=752.577..1334.056 rows=2 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on T1  (cost=0.00..168121.71 rows=5 width=18) (actual time=921.649..1300.556 rows=1 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((external_id)::text = ANY ('{825889935,825904511}'::text[]))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1168882
 Planning Time: 0.592 ms
 Execution Time: 1334.159 ms
```

What could I do to make this query faster? Or probably should I use completely different query?

UPDATE:

Added new query plan as asked @jahrl. It looks like query is faster but previous query plan was made under the load and now it works similar time

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=169121.80..169123.21 rows=12 width=18) (actual time=321.009..322.410 rows=2 loops=1)
   Group Key: external_id
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=169121.80..169123.04 rows=10 width=18) (actual time=321.003..322.403 rows=2 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=168121.77..168121.86 rows=5 width=18) (actual time=318.671..318.672 rows=1 loops=3)
               Group Key: external_id
               ->  Sort  (cost=168121.77..168121.78 rows=5 width=18) (actual time=318.664..318.665 rows=1 loops=3)
                     Sort Key: external_id
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on T1  (cost=0.00..168121.71 rows=5 width=18) (actual time=144.338..318.611 rows=1 loops=3)
                           Filter: ((external_id)::text = ANY ('{825889935,825904511}'::text[]))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1170827
 Planning Time: 0.093 ms
 Execution Time: 322.441 ms
```

Comment: can rewrite your query in this way: 
``` select * from(
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("T1"."external_id") "T1"."external_id", "T1"."timestamp" FROM "T1" 
WHERE "T1"."external_id" IN ('825889935', '825904511')
)t
ORDER BY "T1"."external_id" ASC, "T1"."timestamp" DESC ```

Comment: Do you have indexes on external_id and timestamp? If not, i'd start with at least an `external_id` index if not composite index on both rows if this is a key performance issue.

Comment: Have you tried a lateral join? I imagine postgres would be smart enough to execute them with the same query plan but could be worth trying. I can give an example if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: What data type is `external_id`? If that is a number, you should compare it to one `where external_id in (825889935, 825904511)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a basic `GROUP BY` query will perform better?

```
SELECT "T1"."external_id", MAX("T1"."timestamp") as "timestamp"
FROM "T1" 
WHERE "T1"."external_id" IN ('825889935', '825904511')
GROUP BY "T1"."external_id"
ORDER BY "T1"."external_id" ASC
```

And, as @melcher said, don't forget an ("external_id", "timestamp") index!

Comment: No, I have already tried it. Also I tried it again and I don't see any significant difference

Comment: @Nikitka, do you have the suggested index?

Comment: @Nikitka: could you show us the new query plan?

Comment: There are no indexes on these fields, I would try to add trem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the number of rows removed by the filter and create an index on `external_id`.